# ElasticSearch Multiget issue in Java

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I am new to Java programming and need some help here.
I am running below code and getting appropriate response i.e.

```
{"name1":"Name2","date1":"2016-05-13","message1":"Message2"}
{"name1":"Name0","date1":"2016-05-13","message1":"Message0"}


MultiGetResponse multiGetItemResponses = client.prepareMultiGet()
        .add("loc", "message", "AVSoemK55hnvwxeDfgCc", "AVSoemK55hnvwxeDfgCa").get();


for(MultiGetItemResponse itemResponse: multiGetItemResponses){
GetResponse response2 = itemResponse.getResponse();
        if(response2.isExists()){
        String json2 = response2.getSourceAsString();
        System.out.println(json2);
        }
    }
```

however, when i am trying to parameterise the search text, its not returning any value. Can anyone please guide what might be going wrong here? I have checked that variable abc is returning correct value i.e. "AVSoemK55hnvwxeDfgCc", "AVSoemK55hnvwxeDfgCa"

```
public static boolean getData(String ids){

    String idAry[] = ids.split(",");

    ArrayList<String> idStr = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (String id:idAry){
        idStr.add('"'+id+'"');

    }

    String abc = idStr.toString().replace("[", "").replace("]", "");
    System.out.println(abc);
    MultiGetResponse multiGetItemResponses = client.prepareMultiGet()
            .add("loc", "message", abc).get();
//  MultiGetResponse multiGetItemResponses = client.prepareMultiGet()
//          .add("loc", "message", "AVSoemK55hnvwxeDfgCc", "AVSoemK55hnvwxeDfgCa").get();
//  

    for(MultiGetItemResponse itemResponse: multiGetItemResponses){
    GetResponse response2 = itemResponse.getResponse();
            if(response2.isExists()){
            String json2 = response2.getSourceAsString();
            System.out.println(json2);
            }
        }
    return true;

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need the `abc` variable, i.e. you don't need to transform your list to string. You simply need to construct your query like this, by passing `idList` to your `add()` call as this call will take the index, the type and an `Iterable<String>`, so the `idList` already fits the job.

```
public static boolean getData(String ids){
    String idAry[] = ids.split(",");
    List<String> idList = Arrays.asList(idAry);

    MultiGetResponse multiGetItemResponses = client.prepareMultiGet()
        .add("loc", "message", idList).get();
    ...
```

Comment: how to make a MultiGerResponse query with each query having multiple `where` condition ? Thanks!

Comment: @Vimal feel free to ask a new question